# How to achieve muliple left join in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have 3 tables named stock, product, users. I have a joinning query as below. Can anybody please tell me how to implement it in yii2?

```
SELECT 
    stock.sale_price_per_unit,
    sum(stock.quantity),
    product.product_name,
    users.username

FROM
    stock
LEFT JOIN product ON product.product_id=stock.product_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=stock.seller_id
WHERE stock.product_id=3
GROUP BY stock.seller_id
```

Comment: It is easy to do join after making Yii Relations in model, In this way you can join any number of table with **with** property

Comment: An example of using a 'left join' in the yii2 framework is here: **[/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/#leftJoin](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-joins/#leftJoin)**. I just found it - hope it helps.

Comment: $dataProvider = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
SELECT 
    stock.sale_price_per_unit, sum(stock.quantity), 
    product.product_name, users.username
FROM 
    stock
LEFT JOIN 
    product ON product.product_id=stock.product_id
LEFT JOIN 
    users ON users.user_id=stock.seller_id
WHERE 
    stock.product_id=:id
GROUP BY 
    stock.seller_id")
->bindValue(':id', 3)
->queryAll();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refering to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-active-record.html#joining-with-relations and http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50423-joins-are-back/:

```
$orders = Order::find()->joinWith('customer')->orderBy('customer.id, order.id')->all();
```

so your code should look like:

```
$query = Stock::find()
->joinWith(['product', 'users']);

$items = $query
    ->select([
        'sale_price_per_unit',
        'sum(quantity)',
        'product.product_name',
        'users.username'])
    ->where(['stock.product_id'=>3])
    ->groupBy('seller_id')
    ->all();
```

where relations "product" and "users" declared in Stock model:
HAS_MANY:

```
public function getUsers()
{
  return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['seller_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

HAS_ONE

```
public function getProduct()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id']);
}
```

Comment: Getting unknown property: common\models\Stock::product_name

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code For joins In model  **Geography.php**  here i have model geography and i bind three tables in geography table in yii2

```
#####**Create Relation With Country Table** 

public function getCountry() {
    return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'country_id']);
}

#####**Create Relation With State Table** 

public function getState() {
    return $this->hasOne(State::className(), ['id' => 'state_id']);
}

**#####Create Relation With City Table** 

public function getCity() {
    return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id' => 'city_id']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'DISTINCT t.*';
                                        $criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN `shared_items` AS `si` ON t.workspace_id = si.workspace_id';
                                        $criteria->addCondition('t.status_id != ' . ProjectStatuses::STATUS_CLOSED);
                                        $criteria->addCondition('t.workspace_id = ' . $workspace_id);
```

Comment: Does yii2 support CDbCriteria?

Comment: Ok i got it. But CDbCriteria isnot for yii2.